# How can I custom number of job per second (job/s) that be executed by quartz scheduler?

Tags: spring-boot, quartz

I'm attempting to practice with Quartz Scheduler in a small Spring Boot Application. I really want to know if any way to determined number of job per second (job/s) that be executed by quartz scheduler. I checked all quart properties in documentation but can not find anything.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You can maanage this from your property file though property name is depend on which Job store are you using,

For JDBC Job store, property name is  **org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount**.

Check out http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.7/configuration/ official documentation for respective implementation.
[documentation is for 2.1.7]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But the property mean "number of available threads for concurrent jobs" and not appropriate to my target. For simplest example "threadCount = 5" it means 5 threads are opening for jobs execution and 5 jobs in each thread. But I just want to know each job will be executed in how long, and can I fix it in configuration file. Perhaps Quartz can not do that. I just think so

Comment: Okay, let me check again and will update you if I found anything related to your question. Thanks